# Related Content View with multiple Entity Reference Fields

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities, views

I am trying to create a View to display related content based on shared taxonomy terms from multiple vocabularies.

For example:

I have two content types called **Car** and **Parts**.

I have two vocabularies called **Type** and **Country**.

Content Types:

- Car

  - Entity Reference: Type
  - Entity Reference: Country
- Parts

  - Entity Reference: Type
  - Entity Reference: Country

Vocabularies

- **Type**: sedan, convertible, coupe, van, suv
- **Country**: usa, japan, germany

I would like to display a view of related Parts when viewing a Car node.  Furthermore, I only want to display if both Type and Country match.

I’m able to get either Type or Country matches to display by adding the following relationships.

- Content: Taxonomy terms on node
- (term) Entity Reference: Referencing entity (type)
- (term) Entity Reference: Referencing entity (country)

and a contextual filter of:

- (Content referencing Taxonomy term from field_country) Content: Nid

Basically, switching the relationship on the contextual filter determines whether or not Type or Country matches should be displayed.  I am having trouble figuring out how to display Parts that match both the Type and Country of the Car.

Comment: u haven't created any relationship between two content types . How can you show related Parts when viewing a car node unless you have some field which connects oe establishes relationship between them

Comment: Do you not need to set the relationships as required?

Comment: @ShreyaShetty I have 2 relationships, one for each entity reference field.  However the "Content: Nid" contextual filter only accepts one relationship.  So whatever field I choose for that relationship is the value that is displayed.

Comment: @DanielHarper If I set both relationships to required, then no results are displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to do the following.

1. Create a view based on content of type parts (as a block I'm guessing)
2. Add a relationship "Content: Country (field_country)" using the defaults
3. Add a relationship "Content: Type (field_type)" using the defaults
4. Add a contextual filter for "Taxonomy term: Term ID" with the following settings.

   - **Relationship:** country
   - **Provide default value:** Taxonomy term ID from URL
   - **Load default filter from node page, that's good for related taxonomy blocks**
   - **Limit terms to vocabulary:** Vocabularies country.
   - **Multiple-value handling:** Filter to items that share all terms
5. Add another contextual filter for "Taxonomy term: Term ID" with the following settings.

   - **Relationship:** type
   - **Provide default value:** Taxonomy term ID from URL
   - **Load default filter from node page, that's good for related taxonomy blocks**
   - **Limit terms to vocabulary:** Vocabularies type.
   - **Multiple-value handling: Filter** to items that share all terms.

Now just place your block on all car pages.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write such detailed instructions.  I tried to follow the steps you outlined, however I do not see "Content: Country (field_country)" or "Content: Type (field_type)" as an available relationship.   Do I need to add a different relationship first in order to see those?  Also, I should mention again that I am using Entity Reference fields, not Term Reference fields to tag the nodes with taxonomy terms.  Thanks again for your time and help.

Comment: field_country and field_type just refer to the fields that are on your content types, they were just the field names that I used yours maybe different. I also used the same fields on both content types.

Comment: good point about the reference fields I hadn't noticed that :)

Answer (score 0):

**I finally got it working by adding the following Relationships:**

1. A bridge to the Taxonomy term entity that is referenced via field_type
2. A bridge to the Content entity that is referencing Taxonomy term via field_type (add relationship to #1)
3. A bridge to the Taxonomy term entity that is referenced via field_country
4. A bridge to the Content entity that is referencing Taxonomy term via field_country (add relationship to #3)

**And the following Contextual Filters:**

1. (Content referencing Taxonomy term from field_type) Content: Nid
2. (Content referencing Taxonomy term from field_country) Content: Nid

All relationships need to be required.  And all contextual filters need to have a default value of "Content ID from URL".